# Is it possible to get a legit range info when using a SMT constraint with Z3

Tags: python, constraints, z3, smt, z3py

So basically I am trying to solve the following SMT constraint with a generic constraint solver like Z3:

```
>>> from z3 import *
>>> a = BitVec("a", 32)
>>> b = BitVec("b", 32)
>>> c1 = (a + 32) & (b & 0xff)
>>> c2 = (b & 0xff)
>>> s = Solver()
>>> s.add(c1 == c2)
>>> s.check()
sat
>>> s.model()
[b = 0, a = 4294967199]
```

Note that obviously, the constraint should be `sat` whenever `b` falls within the range of `[0x00000000, 0xffffff00]`.

So here is my question, is it in general feasible for a SMT solver like `Z3` to provide the "range" information, of a satisfiable constraint? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking for a valid "widest" range of values such that your property will be satisfied for *all* numbers in that range, that would be a quantified optimization problem. (Also, what "widest" means in this context can be hard to express.) Currently, neither z3 nor any other SMT solver I'm aware of can handle such problems, unfortunately.

However, if you are looking for the minimum and maximum values of `b` such that your property will hold, then you can use the `Optimize` class for that:

```
from z3 import *

a = BitVec("a", 32)
b = BitVec("b", 32)
c1 = (a + 32) & (b & 0xff)
c2 = (b & 0xff)

s = Optimize()
s.add(c1 == c2)

min_b = s.minimize(b)
max_b = s.maximize(b)
s.set('priority', 'box')
s.check()

print "min b = %s" % format(min_b.value().as_long(), '#x')
print "max b = %s" % format(max_b.value().as_long(), '#x')
```

This prints:

```
min b = 0x0
max b = 0xffffffff
```

[Aside: The max value of `b` differs from what you predicted it would be. But what z3 is saying looks good to me: If you pick `a` to be `0x7fffffdf`, then `a+32` will be `0x7fffffff`, which is all `1`s; and thus `c1` and `c2` will be equivalent for any value of `b`. So nothing here really constrains `b` in any way. Perhaps you had a different constraint in mind?]

But more importantly, note that this does *not* mean your property will be true for all values of `b` in this range: All it's saying is that of all the values of `b` that satisfy your property, these are the minimum and maximum values `b` can assume. (In this particular case, it turns out that all values within that range satisfy it, but that's something we deduced ourselves.) For instance, if you add a constraint that `b` is *not* `5`, you will still get these bounds. I hope that's clear!

Comment: Technically speaking, in the case of Finite-Size Bit-Vectors, it is not necessary to perform any quantified optimization, as it suffices to expand all possible cases in the formulation of the problem. So, both `z3` and `OptiMathSAT` already have, technically speaking, *"all that it takes"* to solve the problem. Having said this, for `32-bit`-sized Bit-Vectors this certainly looks unpractical, so +1 to your answer. @lllllllllllll

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by **Levent Erkok** is valid in general and, in most practical cases, it is the only one which is worth being considered.

However, technically speaking, this is not a problem that is completely beyond the reach of *OMT* solvers, at least when the domain of values being considered is *finite* and, possibly, *small*. In this case, it is possible to simply enumerate all possible values in the formulation of the problem. Naturally, this approach should not be expected to scale very well.

---

**Example.**

The goal of this model is to find the largest interval `delta`, contained in `[low, upp]`, such that for all the values inside the interval a certain *Boolean* property `Prop` holds.

**File:** test.smt2

```
(set-option :produce-models true)

(declare-fun low () (_ BitVec 4))
(declare-fun upp () (_ BitVec 4))
(declare-fun delta () (_ BitVec 4))

(declare-fun Prop () Bool)

(assert (bvule low upp))
(assert (= delta (bvadd upp (bvneg low) (_ bv1 4))))

; Put in relation a domain value with the desired Property
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv0 4)) (bvule (_ bv0 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv1 4)) (bvule (_ bv1 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv2 4)) (bvule (_ bv2 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv3 4)) (bvule (_ bv3 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv4 4)) (bvule (_ bv4 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv5 4)) (bvule (_ bv5 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv6 4)) (bvule (_ bv6 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv7 4)) (bvule (_ bv7 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv8 4)) (bvule (_ bv8 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv9 4)) (bvule (_ bv9 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv10 4)) (bvule (_ bv10 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv11 4)) (bvule (_ bv11 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv12 4)) (bvule (_ bv12 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv13 4)) (bvule (_ bv13 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv14 4)) (bvule (_ bv14 4) upp)) Prop))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv15 4)) (bvule (_ bv15 4) upp)) Prop))

; These are just to make the solution "interesting"
; Your problem should already entail some values bvX for
; which Prop is false
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv5 4)) (bvule (_ bv5 4) upp)) (not Prop)))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv6 4)) (bvule (_ bv6 4) upp)) (not Prop)))
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv13 4)) (bvule (_ bv13 4) upp)) (not Prop)))

(maximize delta)

(check-sat)
(get-objectives)
(get-model)
```

A short explanation. The goal of the objective function is to maximize the size of the interval `[low, upp]`, which is measured by `delta`. The largest value of `delta` is `2^N`, which corresponds to the interval `[0, 2^N - 1]`.

The constraint:

```
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv0 4)) (bvule (_ bv0 4) upp)) Prop))
```

says that, if the value `bv0` is contained in the current interval `[low, upp]`, then the property `Prop` must hold.

The constraint:

```
(assert (=> (and (bvule low (_ bv5 4)) (bvule (_ bv5 4) upp)) (not Prop)))
```

says that, for the value `bv5`, the property `Prop` does not hold. Same for `bv6` and `bv13`. These constraints are just to make the solution interesting. Your problem should already contain some values `bvX` for which property `Prop` cannot be *true*.

The *optimal solution* matches the desired value:

```
~$ time ./optimathsat test.smt2 
sat

(objectives
 (delta (_ bv6 4))
)
( (low (_ bv7 4))
  (upp (_ bv12 4))
  (delta (_ bv6 4))
  (Prop true) )

real    0m0,042s
user    0m0,029s
sys     0m0,013s
```

Naturally, the same formula can also be solved with `z3`.

Comment: Indeed, scale is the issue here. A binary-search based algorithm can be devised for a single variable that can perform well in most cases. But what do you do when you have multiple variables? Even the notion of "maximum interval" becomes rather problematic. For specific problems, Nikolaj pointed out the following paper: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/secguru.pdf I haven't read it in detail yet, but it seems if you have a well-defined problem (like "ethernet address matching") the problem can be solved effectively. Definitely worth checking out!

Comment: @LeventErkok yup, I definitively agree :)

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Thank you so much Patrick. Could you post the test.smt2 as well? Indeed it is a bit difficult for me to comprehend your code snippet.. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @lllllllllllll I updated the answer. Beware of scalability issues when using BVs of 32 bits. In my opinion, it is not unreasonable to use smaller-sized BVs (e.g. 8 bits), because there is nothing special --arithmetically speaking-- about 32 bits BVs. In this case, constant values need to be scaled down as well. As Levent Erkok cleverly pointed out, in the case that you want to keep track of multiple domain intervals, you first have to decide how to define the *"maximum interval"* for your application. You might also consider using either a Boxed/Independent optimization, or a Pareto one.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Thank you Patrick! The updated answer makes a lot more sense to me. Not sure how slow it could become in my settings (constraints of 32-bit bit vectors). I guess I can have a try first. I am also thinking to explore some "sub-maximum" range for this problem. In case you have time and are interested, I will appreciate if you can shed some lights on [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733658/suboptimal-way-to-get-a-legit-range-info-when-using-a-smt-constraint-with-z3). Take care!

Comment: @lllllllllllll I'll be sure to take a look when I come back from holiday